# how to put dictionary data in to data frame and can that data frame be converted in csv file?

Tags: python, dataframe

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


heart_rate = [random.randrange(45,125) for _ in range(100)]
blood_pressure_systolic = [random.randrange(140,230) for _ in range(100)]
blood_pressure_dyastolic = [random.randrange(90,140) for _ in range(100)]
temperature = [random.randrange(34,42) for _ in range(100)]
respiratory_rate = [random.randrange(8,35) for _ in range(100)]
pulse_oximetry = [random.randrange(95,100) for _ in range(100)]

vitalsign = {'HR' : 'heart_rate',
             'BPS' : 'blood_pressure_systolic',
             'BPD' : 'blood_pressure_dyastolic',
             'T' : 'temperature',
             'RR' : 'respiratory_rate',
             'PO' : 'pulse_oximetry'}
pd.DataFrame(vitalsign)
```

I want an output something like this

```
heart   blood   pulse   temp
5.1     3.5     1.4     0.2 
4.9     3       1.4     0.2
```

Comment: You can just define a dict with the column names as the key and the lists as the values and pass this to `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: Remove the quote around the values in the dictionary.

Comment: DataFrame.from_dict(vitalsign)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. What you want is:

```
vitalsign = {'heart' : heart_rate,
             'blood' : blood_pressure_systolic,
             'temp' : temperature,
             'pulse' : pulse_oximetry}
df = pd.DataFrame(vitalsign)
```

To convert this to .csv:

```
df.to_csv('your_file_name.csv')
```